# King of Tokyo- Dice resolution

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Does a roll 1,2,3,energy,heart,claw give a 9 fame reward of "9" along with the one energy, one health and 1 attack results?
I picked this notion up playing the game prior to purchasing my own copy of KoT 2016 but can't find anything stated in the rules.
Could this be a resolution from a previous version?

Answer (score 9):

You only get 9 victory points from that combination if you have the Complete Destruction power card.

> Complete Destruction
>   
> 3{Energy}
>   
> Keep
>   
> If you roll {1}{2}{3}{Heart}{Claw}{Energy}
>   
> gain 9{Victory Point} in addition to the regular results.

[image: Complete Destruction]